# Separate string together and print to file in C

Tags: c

I am trying to separate the following string read from a txt:

> CristinaRodriguezRiveraComputacion210302414RamiroSilvaPerezIndustrial217890453PatriciaDuranSanchezCivil215643525RaulColinGranadosComputacion215678342

but when separating it and wanting to print the code, it is omitting this:

> RaulColinGranadosComputacion215678342

for some reason it is omitting only that piece of string and I would like to know what I am doing wrong in my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
   char name[15];
   char apPat[15];
   char apMat[15];
   char degree[15];
   char id[15];
} Student;

Student al;

int main() {
    FILE* ent = fopen("DatosEntrada.txt","r");
    FILE* sal = fopen("SalidaBytes.txt","a");

    if (ent != NULL) {
        char name[15];
        char father[15];
        char mother[15];
        char degree[15];
        char id[15];

        memset(name, 0, sizeof(name));
        memset(father, 0, sizeof(father));
        memset(mother, 0, sizeof(mother));
        memset(degree, 0, sizeof(degree));
        memset(id, 0, sizeof(id));

        fseek(ent, 0, SEEK_END);  //file length
        int longarch = ftell(ent);
        rewind(ent); //go back to the start

        char dinamic[longarch];

        fscanf(ent, "%s", &dinamic);

        int longitud = strlen(dinamic);
        int counter = 0, iterator = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++) {
            if (isupper(dinamic[i])) {
                if (islower(dinamic[i-1]) && islower(dinamic[i+1])) {
                    counter++;
                }

                if (counter == 0) { //name
                    iterator = 0;
                    name[iterator] = dinamic[i];
                    iterator++;
                }
                else if (counter == 1) { //father
                    iterator = 0;
                    father[iterator] = dinamic[i];
                    iterator++;
                }
                else if (counter == 2) {  //mother
                    iterator = 0;
                    mother[iterator] = dinamic[i];
                    iterator++;
                }
                else if (counter == 3) {  //degree
                    iterator = 0;
                    degree[iterator] = dinamic[i];
                    iterator++;
                }
            }
            else if (islower(dinamic[i])) {
                if (counter == 0) { //name
                    name[iterator] = dinamic[i];
                    iterator++;
                }
                else if (counter == 1) {  //father
                    father[iterator] = dinamic[i];
                    iterator++;
                }
                else if (counter == 2) { //mother
                    mother[iterator] = dinamic[i];
                    iterator++;
                }
                else if (counter == 3) { //degree
                    degree[iterator] = dinamic[i];
                    iterator++;
                }
            }
            else if (isdigit(dinamic[i])) {
                if (islower(dinamic[i-1]) && isdigit(dinamic[i+1])) {
                    iterator = 0;
                    counter++;
                }
                else if (isupper(dinamic[i+1]) && isdigit(dinamic[i-1])) {
                    id[iterator] = dinamic[i];
                    counter = 0;

                    strcpy(al.name, name);
                    strcpy(al.apPat, father);
                    strcpy(al.apMat, mother);
                    strcpy(al.degree, degree);
                    strcpy(al.id, id);

                    fwrite(&al, sizeof(Student), 1, sal);
                    memset(&al, 0, sizeof(Student));

                    memset(name, 0, sizeof(name));
                    memset(father, 0, sizeof(father));
                    memset(mother, 0, sizeof(mother));
                    memset(degree, 0, sizeof(degree));
                    memset(id, 0, sizeof(id));
                }

                if (counter == 4) {  //id
                    id[iterator] = dinamic[i];
                    iterator++;
                }
            }
        }

        printf("\nCreated File\n");
        fclose(ent);
        fclose(sal);
    }
    else {
       fprintf(stdout, "ERROR: %s", strerror(errno));
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose the first character of the string is upper case (which it is, btw). Therefore `if (isupper(dinamic[i]))` will be true for `i` when `0`. Now look at the code. What do you think `if (islower(dinamic[i - 1]) && islower(dinamic[i + 1]))` is going to do, and particularly, the `dinamic[i - 1]` part? You're under-breaching your array, invoking *undefined behavior* when doing so. That is the first problem I saw, and stopped looking.

Comment: @WhozCraig How do you recommend handling the first digit? Since I really can't think of a way to implement it, I tried several things but nothing works for me :/

Comment: This is almost certainly wrong: `fscanf(ent,"%s",&dinamic);`  dinamic is an array of char so it can be updated directly so you wouldn't pass a pointer to that into fscanf.  Surely it should be `fscanf(ent,"%s",dinamic);`

Comment: @JerryJeremías how do i correct that? what do you recommend to use?

Comment: I suspect there are a considerably collection of logic problems beyond the underrun, such as what Jerry just pointed out. And "how do I correct that?" He literally just **showed you**.

Comment: @WhozCraig beginner programmer, sorry :(

Comment: Without seeing the input, it's as if you measured the file size, then - by luck or good fortune - the `fscanf()` has overwritten the final presumed '\n' with a '\0'... Please learn about `fread()` and stay away from the `scanf()` family of functions...

Comment: I think this is wrong as well.  `int longarch = ftell(ent);` returns 149 because there are 149 characters in the file and then `char dinamic[longarch];` allocates space but not enough for the string termination character so when you read the string you write past the end of the array.

Comment: @JerryJeremías I correct the null character, thanks :)

Comment: The reason the last bit isn't written is `}else if(   isupper(dinamic[i+1]) && isdigit(dinamic[i-1]) ){`  When dinamic[i+1] is the string termination character it won't be upper case.  So ytou need `}else if( (isupper(dinamic[i+1]) || dinamic[i+1]=='\0') && isdigit(dinamic[i-1]) ){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about your loop counter...

```
for(int i=0;i<longitud;i++){
```

When you (fortunately) reach the end of the array of chars, you have `buffered` the last person's info, but your loop terminates and the last person's info is never output.

Move the "print" operation to a separate function that is called from within the loop (as you have) AND called again after the loop has terminated...

Comment: Thank you very much, this has corrected my problem and thanks for the other advice. Sorry, I'm a beginner programmer :(

Comment: If you "accept" this answer, then please click the button to flag it as accepted. (PS: no one was 'born' with programming skills... Keep at it :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to learn too much :)

Answer (score 0):

Now that your code is working, here is a version (bypassing the "read from file" part) for educational purposes.

If you go very slowly and think about what's happening at each step, perhaps you will see how to condense code and avoid mistakes/errors that can creep in when there's just too much code to scroll through.

Good luck on your journey.

```
void showFlds( char flds[][15], int n ) {
    printf( "****\n" );
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        printf( "'%-15s'\n", flds[i] );
    printf( "****\n" );
}

int main() {
    char *in =
        "CristinaRodriguezRiveraComputacion210302414"
        "RamiroSilvaPerezIndustrial217890453"
        "PatriciaDuranSanchezCivil215643525"
        "RaulColinGranadosComputacion215678342";

    const int nFlds = 5;
    int fldCnt = 0;
    char fldCopys[5][15];
    int cCnt = 0;

    putchar( '(' );
    bool firstDig = true;
    for( char *cp = in; *cp; cp++ ) {
        if( cp > in && ( isupper( *cp ) || ( isdigit( *cp ) && firstDig ) ) ) {
            fldCopys[ fldCnt++ ][ cCnt ] = '\0';
            if( fldCnt < nFlds ) {
                putchar( ' ' );
            } else {
                printf( ")\n" );
                showFlds( fldCopys, fldCnt );
                putchar( '(' );
                fldCnt = 0;
            }
            cCnt = 0;
        }
        putchar( *cp );
        fldCopys[ fldCnt ][ cCnt++ ] = *cp;
        firstDig = !isdigit( *cp );
    }
    printf( ")\n" );
    fldCopys[ fldCnt++ ][ cCnt ] = '\0';
    showFlds( fldCopys, fldCnt );

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
(Cristina Rodriguez Rivera Computacion 210302414)
****
'Cristina       '
'Rodriguez      '
'Rivera         '
'Computacion    '
'210302414      '
****
(Ramiro Silva Perez Industrial 217890453)
****
'Ramiro         '
'Silva          '
'Perez          '
'Industrial     '
'217890453      '
****
(Patricia Duran Sanchez Civil 215643525)
****
'Patricia       '
'Duran          '
'Sanchez        '
'Civil          '
'215643525      '
****
(Raul Colin Granados Computacion 215678342)
****
'Raul           '
'Colin          '
'Granados       '
'Computacion    '
'215678342      '
****
```